# How many scenarios can have a single feature file for cucumber?

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I am using Cucumber to automate my e2e, and a feature file has so many scenarios. I would like to know, with the code standards, do we have any limitations on the number of scenarios in a single feature file?

Asking coding standards before implementing my ideas